# Optimization techniques in inserting huge amount of data in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I want to insert around 81000 rows into mysql table but it is taking too long to do it,
for inserting these many rows it takes 9.5 mins and just selecting those many values takes 7.5 mins. Does anyone know how to optimize insert query??

and also I don't understand why cursor shows one row more than total number rows in table. ??

Comment: What have you tried/looked at so far? Answering this requires some more information - what is the table structure? How are you doing your insert/selects? Are there lots of indexes (could explain slow insert, but probably doesn't explain slow select)? You might also want to look at your my.ini or my.cnf settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try [locking the table before inserting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) (and unlocking after).

You could also use [extended inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_extended-insert).

That could speed up insert.

As for selecting, I would say you're probably doing a complex query without indexes.
But you need to be more explicit, we can't help you much without further info.